# Need advice to prevent runoff water from going into neighbor's yard

Tags: water, concrete, drainage, driveway

I'm looking for some advice on what I can do to prevent runoff water from going into my neighbor's yard. I am an auto detailer so I am constantly washing cars in my driveway. The neighbor also parks his truck and RV camper in the dirt section of the yard. Here is a picture so you can see what I am talking about. :-) [image]

Comment: It may be easier all around to offer to split the cost of paving your neighbours drive.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - I wish you were my neighbor.  Would love to split costs with my neighbors to upgrades to my house.  He is just trying to be nice.  There is no laws on his water run-off.  Also if both your driveways are the property line you can set some edging on there but it will probably be ran over eventually.

Comment: It's not about being nice. It's about solving the problem, which is water on a dirt drive.  I can spend 1500 stopping the water, or I can spend 1000 on half his driveway.

Comment: Since the water runoff is due to commercial activity, he may  actually be obligated to contain it.

Comment: Consider one of the low-water car washing systems out there?

Comment: @DMoore - I'm not sure that there are no laws on water runoff -- if water runs off his driveway and damages the neighbors property, he may very well be responsible for damages since the driveway is an 'improvement' to the property that alters the natural flow of water, much how he'd be responsible if his sloped roof dumped water on the neighbors property. This is especially true if the water runoff is caused by commercial activity at a residential house.

Comment: @johnny -  It is absurd to think that anyone would be liable for ground run-off.  I have never heard of it.  I have seen properties that were completely regraded and caused a huge run-off issue and the affected owners having no recourse but to regrade their property.  This case has none of these characteristics and really is just this guy trying to be nice because neighbor hasn't paved.

Answer (score 1):

..Your driveway would be the cracked concrete slab to the left, I assume?

If the picture is not misleading, there appears to be some slope towards the street. If so, rent a concrete saw or buy a concrete blade for a saw you own (but unless you own a water-cooled saw, a rental saw that is water-cooled will generally do a better job, faster) and cut a bunch of grooves 1/2" (or so) deep leading to the curb/gutter at streetside.

That may be all you need to do, or you may need to make some sort of raised edging at the right side of the driveway. That would probably best suit the area if formed from concrete, but something like a rubber glue-down garage door bottom seal (the type that's stuck to the floor, not the type that's stuck to the door) might be quicker and cheaper, until it dies in the sun and needs to be replaced.

[image: Clopay door seal image from Amazon]

Answer (score 1):

You could offer to install a trenchdrain into your neighbours sand. depending on your runoff, that should solve the problem.

unless you want to go with the above solution and build a mound, which may or may not be a better solution depending on the way the water runs, i.e. you dont really want the water to pool on your side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Epoxy a bunch of bricks and/or pressure treated 2x4s to the driveway.
The climate is super-dry, and because of the pitch of your driveway and the amount of water on it, you only really need to contain about a 1/2' high wall of water, and it doesn't matter if it leaks a bit as long as most of the water is directed down the drain.

For the truly cheap, laying out a bunch of pressure treated 2x4s along the edge is likely to work; put them back in the house when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but here's an idea: buy another hose and attach it to your existing hose; wash the cars in the parking lane on the street instead of your driveway.